# Proof Reference For Doob's First Stopping Time Theorem

Tags: probability, martingales

I am reading through a proof of Doob's First (Bounded) Stopping Time Theorem, and I am not really following. Can somebody either provide a good reference, or be able to prove it?

For a martingale $X$, and for stopping times $S, T$, with $S \le T \le c$, where $c > 0$ is a uniform bound, we have that $\mathbb{E}[X_T | \mathcal{F}_S] = X_S$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the $H$-transform of a martingale? (Also called the Doob transform, possibly other names as well...)

Comment: @AlexOrtiz no. Completely new to martingale theory. and I am looking for an elementary proof. So, the proof we were given in class (that I am not following) goes along the lines of showing first that $|X_T| \le \sum_{i \le c} |X_i| \in L^1$ (why is this even necessary? isn't $X_T \in L^1$ by the fact that it's a martingale?) and then playing with the stopping time $U = S \mathbb{1}_A + T \mathbb{1}_{A^c}$ for arbitrary $A \in \mathcal{F}_S$. But I'm not following.

Comment: Part of the statement $\mathbb E[X_T|\mathcal F_S] = X_S$ is that we are allowed to take conditional expectation of $X_T$ in the first place (we need to prove $X_T\in L^1$). You are right that this would be unnecessary if $T$ were a deterministic time, but the issue comes when $T$ is allowed to be random. Then it's not a part of the assumption that $X$ is a martingale that $X_T\in L^1$, and this doesn't necessarily hold for unbounded stopping times, as the proof suggests. The proof I am familiar with also uses the stopping time $U$.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz then can you write up a quick proof? For example, I don't understand why the bound $|X_T| \le \sum_{i \le c} |X_i|$ holds to begin with.

Comment: Unfortunately the proof is not particularly quick, though I hope it is understandable. I left things for you to check, but let me know if you feel any large pieces are missing/unmanageable.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an outline based on the presentation in Durrett's book *[Probability: Theory and Examples](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ertd/PTE/pte.html).* Note that Durrett doesn't prove this result himself, instead relegating it to the exercises, but I'll try to sketch the main parts.

Here is the outline of the proof. $\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb E}\newcommand{\F}{\mathcal F}$

0. $X_S,X_T\in L^1$. ($X_T\in L^1$ is needed for $\E[X_T\mid\F_S]$ to be well-defined.)
1. $\E X_S= \E X_T$.
2. For $A\in\F_S$ arbitrary,  $U = \newcommand{\1}{\mathbb 1}S\1_A + T\1_{A^c}$ is a stopping time.
3. Using $U$, we will strengthen the conclusion of 1. to $X_S= \E[X_T\mid \F_S]$.

*Proof of 0.* Since $T\le c$, and $T$ is integer-valued, $T\le \lfloor c\rfloor$, or in other words, we may as well assume that $c$ is itself an integer. We can write $X_T$ according to the value of $T$ as
$$ X_T = \sum_{i=1}^c X_i\1_{\{T=i\}}.$$
Each of the variables in the sum is integrable, and the sum is finite since $c<\infty$, so the proof is immediate. The proof for $X_S$ is exactly the same. $\square$

*Proof of 1.* Consider the variable $H_n = \1_{\{S<n\le T\}}$. You can check that $H_n$ is a previsible process (meaning $H_n$ is $\F_{n-1}$-measurable for every $n$), hence $(H\cdot X)_n$ defined by $$(H\cdot X)_n:=\sum_{m=1}^nH_m(X_m-X_{m-1})$$
is also a martingale. From the definition, you can also see that we can express $(H\cdot X)_n$ more simply as
$$(H\cdot X)_n = X_{n\wedge T}-X_{n\wedge S}$$ where $a\wedge b := \min\{a,b\}$. We have already noted that this is a martingale, and since $c\ge T\ge S$ a.s., we have
$$ \E(X_T-X_S) =: \E(H\cdot X)_c = \E(H\cdot X)_0 = 0 $$
so $\E X_T= \E X_S$. $\square$

*Proof of 2.* Exercise.

*Proof of 3.* By the definition of $\E[X_T\mid \F_S]$, it suffices to show that $\E(X_S;A) = \E(X_T;A)$ for arbitrary $A\in\F_S$. Let $U$ be the stopping time from 2. Then it is clear that $S\le U\le T$. By the result of 1., we know
$$\E X_S = \E X_U = \E X_T.$$
Decomposing each of the above three terms as
$$
\E X_\ast = \E[X_\ast;A] + \E[X_\ast;A^c]
$$
and simplifying finishes off 3., and the proof of the claim. $\square$

**Remarks.** If $H_n$ is $\F_{n-1}$ measurable for each $n$, then $H$ is sometimes called a predictable sequence instead of a previsible sequence. $H$ is sometimes referred to as a "gambling system" in the interpretation of $X_n$ as the net winnings of a (fair) game at time $n$ if you had bet one dollar each round. The process $H\cdot X$ is the $H$-transform of $X$ (or the Doob transform of $X$ by $H$, or a discrete stochastic integral of $X$, or ...). You can think of $(H\cdot X)_n$ as representing the net winnings at time $n$ if you bet $H$ dollars each round. From this perspective, cooking up stopping times to include into the definition of $H$ is very natural since you can imagine devising a sequence of bets for the subsequent rounds you play based on the information you have gained by the end of your last round.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize - must $S, T : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$? (Consequently, is $c \in \mathbb{N}$, as well?) that would already clear up a lot of my confusion.

Comment: @JoeShmo: In your case, I believe yes $S,T$ are integer-valued, and the index of the martingale $X$ is an integer. There is a similar result for the case of continuous-time martingales, but the proof is even more involved there. (I think at least one proof of the continuous case uses the discrete case.)

Comment: thank you. The major misunderstanding here for me was that I thought $S,T$ were real-valued. The majority of what you said was already on the board (and I did manage to dig it up in Durrett's book), but yours was an excellent presentation, and I am accepting it as the answer.

Comment: @JoeShmo: I added a few remarks about H-transforms to the end of my answer. The proof of the continuous-time case is a little more involved, but I think it shouldn't be too hard to find one online that uses the discrete-time case as a lemma/part of the proof. Glad this was helpful!

Comment: yeah, it's not hard to imagine that it's more or less just this argument on a fine grid.